# Javascript mouse out issue

Tags: javascript

Hi i dont know so much of javascript and currently trying to debug. http://llondon.online-folio.com/index.php on slider area on mouse over the slider stops rotating, but when i mouse out that area it still remains idle and doesnt start rotation again. this is the plugin for slider: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent.htm

this is the code stoping the rotation on mouse over:

```
this.tabs[i].onmouseover = function() {
    tabinstance.expandtab(this)
    tabinstance.cancelautorun() //stop auto cycling of tabs (if running)
    return false
}
```

to start the rotation there is a function

```
.autorun()
```

so can some one write me some lines of code so on mouse out this starts rotating again.

Comment: "*can some one write me some lines of code*" - No. We're here to help you with problems you encounter, not to do your work. Please try something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a mouse out event for this?
eg
this.tabs[i].onmouseout = function() {
    tabinstance.autorun(); //restart auto cycling of tabs
    return false
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try to using Jquerytools http://jquerytools.org/